# Xaml oxyplot HighLowSeries Items Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, oxyplot

I want to define a `HighLowSeries` via XAML. Since `HighLowSeries-graphs` are not available in the `oxyplot.wpf` namespace I've created the following class:

```
public class HighLowSeries : OxyPlot.Wpf.XYAxisSeries
{

    public HighLowSeries()
    {
        this.InternalSeries = new OxyPlot.Series.HighLowSeries();
    }

    public override OxyPlot.Series.Series CreateModel()
    {
        this.SynchronizeProperties(this.InternalSeries);
        return this.InternalSeries;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The synchronize properties.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="series">
    /// The series.
    /// </param>
    protected override void SynchronizeProperties(OxyPlot.Series.Series series)
    {
        base.SynchronizeProperties(series);
        var s = (OxyPlot.Series.HighLowSeries)series;

        foreach (HighLowItem item in s.Items)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("HighLowSeries " + item.X);
        }

    }

}
```

In my Window, I use the `HighLowSeries` the following way:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
    xmlns:Tmp="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Oxy:PlotView Width="300"
                    Height="300" 
                    Title="Test">
        <Oxy:PlotView.Series>
            <Tmp:HighLowSeries ItemsSource="{Binding list}" />
        </Oxy:PlotView.Series>
    </Oxy:PlotView>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

In the code behind of the Window, I have the following code:

```
        private IList<HighLowItem> _list;

    public IList<HighLowItem> list
    {
        get
        {
            return this._list;
        }
        set
        {
            this._list = value;
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.list = new List<HighLowItem>();

        list.Add(new HighLowItem(10, 8, 3, 2, 5));
        list.Add(new HighLowItem(12, 7, 4, 4, 2));
        list.Add(new HighLowItem(18, 4, 1, 2, 3));

        this.DataContext = this;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

When I start the application there is only a tiny horizontal line at (0,0): 
[image: HighLowSeries]

Additionally there is a `Trace.WriteLine` in `HighLowSeries.SynchronizeProperties()` where I print out the X-coordinates of the `HighLowElements` in the Items-Collection. The quantity of outputs matches the elements in the list-property of `MainWindow`. But the X-coordinate is always 0 (as well as the other properties of the `HighLowElements`). 
When I implement my own `LineSeries` the same way, everything works as it should.

Is this a bug in oxyplot? Or am I missing anything? Creating the `HighLowSeries` via code is not an option at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the spot, where the list with `DataPoints` is cleared.

In the source code ([OxyPlot Source HighLowItemSeries)](https://oxyplot.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/OxyPlot/Series/HighLowSeries.cs)

There is this method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Updates the data.
/// </summary>
protected internal override void UpdateData()
{
    if (this.ItemsSource == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    this.items.Clear();

    // Use the mapping to generate the points
    if (this.Mapping != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in this.ItemsSource)
        {
            this.items.Add(this.Mapping(item));
        }
        return;
    }

    var filler = new ListFiller<HighLowItem>();
    filler.Add(this.DataFieldX, (p, v) => p.X = Axis.ToDouble(v));
    filler.Add(this.DataFieldHigh, (p, v) => p.High = Axis.ToDouble(v));
    filler.Add(this.DataFieldLow, (p, v) => p.Low = Axis.ToDouble(v));
    filler.Add(this.DataFieldOpen, (p, v) => p.Open = Axis.ToDouble(v));
    filler.Add(this.DataFieldClose, (p, v) => p.Close = Axis.ToDouble(v));
    filler.FillT(this.items, this.ItemsSource);
}
```

Since `this.Mapping` equals null, the `mapping` is bypassed and a `filler object` is added.

The comment of the `Mapping-field` says how to set the value:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the mapping delegate.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The mapping.</value>
    /// <remarks>Example: series1.Mapping = item => new HighLowItem(((MyType)item).Time,((MyType)item).Value);</remarks>
    public Func<object, HighLowItem> Mapping { get; set; }
```

If I change the `SynchronizeProperties` method to the following everything works as it should.

```
    protected override void SynchronizeProperties(OxyPlot.Series.Series series)
    {
        base.SynchronizeProperties(series);
        var s = (OxyPlot.Series.HighLowSeries)series;
        s.Mapping = item => new HighLowItem(((HighLowItem)item).X, ((HighLowItem)item).High, ((HighLowItem)item).Low, ((HighLowItem)item).Open, ((HighLowItem)item).Close);
    }
```